# Extracting two numbers from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like the following one:

> "some value is 25 but must not be bigger then 12"

I want to extract the two numbers from the string.

The numbers are integers.

There might be no text before the first number and some text after the second number.

I tried to do it with a regexp and groups, but failed miserably:

```
public MessageParser(String message) {
    Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d?).*(\\d?).*");
    Matcher matcher = stringWith2Numbers.matcher(message);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        couldParse = false;
        firstNumber = 0;
        secondNumber = 0;
    } else {
        final String firstNumberString = matcher.group(1);
        firstNumber = Integer.valueOf(firstNumberString);
        final String secondNumberString = matcher.group(2);
        secondNumber = Integer.valueOf(secondNumberString);

        couldParse = true;
    }
}
```

Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `".*"` patterns are being greedy, as is their wont, and are gobbling up as much as they can -- which is going to be the entire string.  So that first `".*"` is matching the entire string, rendering the rest moot.  Also, your `"\\d?"` clauses indicate a single digit which happens to be optional, neither of which is what you want.

This is probably more in line with what you're shooting for:

`Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+).*?");`

Of course, since you don't really care about the stuff before or after the numbers, why bother with them?

`Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile("(\\d+).*?(\\d+)");`

That ought to do the trick.

**Edit:** Taking time out from writing butt-kickingly awesome comics, Alan Moore pointed out some problems with my solution in the comments.  For starters, if you have only a single multi-digit number in the string, my solution gets it wrong.  Applying it to "This 123 is a bad string" would cause it to return "12" and "3" when it ought to simply fail.  A better regex would stipulate that there MUST be at least one non-digit character separating the two numbers, like so:

`Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)");`

Also, `matches()` applies the pattern to the *entire* string, essentially bracketing it in `^` and `$`; `find()` would do the trick, but that's not what the OP was using.  So sticking with `matches()`, we'd need to bring back in those "useless" clauses in front of and after the two numbers.  (Though having them explicitly match non-digits instead of the wildcard is better form.)  So it would look like:

`Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D*");`

... which, it must be noted, is damn near identical to jjnguy's answer.

Comment: Wouldn't the ".*" between the number patterns "eat up" the second number?

Comment: Nope.  The question mark coming after the star indicates it should match the SHORTEST possible string it can -- thus, it'll match everything before the second number.

Comment: ... although, because the two digit clauses aren't optional anymore, the question mark is less important -- if you're absolutely certain there will be two and ONLY two numbers in the string, you don't need it.  It matters if there are more digits, though.  Using "1 and 2 and 3" as a sample string: with the question mark, you get 1 and 2 being fished out.  Without, 1 and 3 would be the two extracted values.

Comment: You can avoid that problem by using `\\D*` instead of `.*`, as @jinguy did.  But the one in the middle should be `\\D+`, as I explained in the comment to his answer.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but you're right; my solution will be fine if there really are two numbers in the input text, but if the text is "I have a 42 number", it will come back with "4" and "2" when it ought to simply fail.  And I didn't even think of the matches/find thing, which has tripped me up in the past.  Will edit answer, seeing as it got accepted despite these deficiencies.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Your pattern should look more like:

```
Pattern stringWith2Numbers = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D*");
```

You need to accept `\\d+` because it can be one or more digits.

Comment: Wouldn't \D*(\d+)^\D]*(\d+)^\D* be slightly more appropriate? As we explicitly don't want digits and . has the potential to match a digit before we get to \d.

Comment: That second `\\D*` should be `\\D+`. As it is, your regex could match the string `"42"`, leaving `"4"` in group #1 and `"2"` in group #2.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches, but everything gets eaten up by your first `.*` and the rest matches the empty string.

Change your regex to `"\\D*(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D*"`.

This should be read as: At least one numeric digit followed by at least one character that isn't a numeric digit, followed by at least one numeric digit.

Comment: The leading and trailing `.*` are necessary if you use the `matches()` method as the OP is doing.  Your regex will work with the `find()` method, which performs the more traditional "it's in there somewhere" kind of regex matching.