# extracting long/float numbers from a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have input like this ==>
2 book at 12.99
4 potato chips at 3.99

I want to extract the numeric values from each line and store them in variables
for example in the line.. 2 book at 12.99 i want to extract Qauntity =2 and Price =12.99 
from the given string

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717601/extracting-two-numbers-from-a-string?rq=1

Comment: for parsing ints, longs, floats, doubles, etc, use `Long.parseLong(String s)` and the equilvalents. Also, to get two Strings containing only the numbers, you could try `String.split("\\D+"); //maybe needs to be a *`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+(?:.\\d+)?)");
Matcher mr = p.matcher("4 potato chips at 3.99");
if (mr.find()) {
    System.out.println( mr.group(1) + " :: " + mr.group(2) );
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

4 :: 3.99

Comment: Hi Anubhava ..thanks a lot ,.but in the output the fractional part is being treated as a separate number ..This is how the Input and output looks 
This is the output for the input  1 book at 12.99
 1 potato chips at 3.99   it skips
Quantity is12.0
Price is99.0
Quantity is3.0
Price is99.0

Comment: As per your example in your input you have only 1 item quantity and it's price. You can't pass an input of chips and books to this regex.

Comment: No actually i am doing that in a loop .the problem is that instead of it taking quantity as 1 and price as 12.99 ..it skips 1 and takes quantity as 12.0 and its fractional part .99 as Price =99.0 ...so basically it is skipping the quantity and takes decimal and fractional part of the price instead

Comment: OK can you post your code in your question that reproduces this problem. It will be easy for me to understand and fix then.

Comment: Matcher mr=null;String Quantity=tokens[i];
QuantityItem = Quantity.split(del);for(int j=0;j<QuantityItem.length;j++)
{
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+(?:.\\d+)?)");
mr = p.matcher(QuantityItem[j]);}
if (mr.find()) {      Quant=Float.parseFloat(mr.group(0));       System.out.println("Quantityis"+Quant);         price=Float.parseFloat(mr.group(1));
 System.out.println("Price is"+price);
}

Comment: Also provide `QuantityItem` array values.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

```
(\d+)[^\d]+([+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vX0Tmkx4SADAAv82)**

---

### Description [(Example)](http://regex101.com/r/yZ4aS6)

```
/^(\d+)[^\d]+([+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)$/gm
^ Start of line
1st Capturing group (\d+)
    \d 1 to infinite times [greedy] Digit [0-9]
Negated char class [^\d] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches any character except:
    \d Digit [0-9]
2nd Capturing group ([+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)
    Char class [+-] 0 to 1 times [greedy] matches:
        +- One of the following characters +-
    Char class [0-9] 1 to 3 times [greedy] matches:
        0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9
    (?:,?[0-9]{3}) Non-capturing Group 0 to infinite times [greedy]
        , 0 to 1 times [greedy] Literal ,
    Char class [0-9] 3 times [greedy] matches:
        0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9
    (?:\.[0-9]{2}) Non-capturing Group 0 to 1 times [greedy]
        \. Literal .
    Char class [0-9] 2 times [greedy] matches:
        0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9
$ End of line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

***Capture Group 1:** Contains the Quantity*

***Capture Group 2:** Contains the Amount*

---

### Java

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)[^\\d]+([+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

***Note:** This java is just an example, I don't code in Java*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class. Below is the working example:

```
MessageFormat f = new MessageFormat("{0,number,#.##} {2} at {1,number,#.##}");
try {
    Object[] result = f.parse("4 potato chips at 3.99");
    System.out.print(result[0]+ ":" + (result[1]));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    // handle parse error
}
```

Comment: won't this only work if the numbers are less than $10? or does Java handle this? more of a personal inquiry

Comment: Yes, provided example will work only with less than $10 but if you change '{1,number,#.##}' with {1,number} or {1,number,######.##} it will work perfectly. Comprehensive documentation of all possible format type (for example number) or format style (for example ##.###_ could be found in class' javadoc. You can choose any formmating attributes suitable for your particular situation.